# How to define minimal column width in a table

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table with 2 columns that spans over the whole screen. The table's could would be something like this:

```
<table style="width:100%">
   <tr>
       <td>Column1</td>
       <td>Column2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I want column 1 to cover as little width as necessary to display its content without forcing linebreaks. I don't want to specify the width in pixels or percentage because the content varies a lot.

Is this achievable with CSS?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: I think this is achievable if you use display: flex. You would set width auto on both and apply flex-grow: 1; on the second column?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done using `flex` and assigning `flex-grow: 1` to the column you wish to span the remaining width:

```css
tr {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    flex-direction: row;

    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: center;

    flex-wrap: wrap;

    background-color: orange;
}
td {
    width: auto;
    background-color: red;
}
td:nth-of-type(2) {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Column1</td>
        <td>Column2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hmmm... I exactly use this code with <td style="flex-grow:1">Column2</td> on a new page with no other CSS defined and both columns are 50%